# React material-ui: How to map over all Icons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to map over all `@material-ui/icons` in React.

I can import a single Icon like this

```
import IconName icons from '@material-ui/icons/IconName'
```

and display it

```
<IconName />
```

I want to import all available icons

```
import * as icons from '@material-ui/icons';
```

and display them all... something like

```
icons.map(Icon => <Icon />)
```

Any other way would do as well, I just don't want to store a static dictionary of all icon codes.

Answer (score 0):

you have to transform names of each single icon to underscore_case and place it between Icon tag from '@material-ui/core/Icon'.

AddCircle => add_circle